# using socket on angular factory

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, node.js

im trying to use angular service in order to pass from my node js server into my view json objects. 
i debuged the service function and saw that it is really getting the objects but when i returned the objects array im getting on $scope.messages = undefined.

my server code:

```
var express = require("express");
var url = require("url");
var app = express(); // express.createServer();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(8080);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
, format = require('util').format;

var insertMsg, Collection;
var socketMap = {};

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/EladGuy', function(err, db) {
    if(err) 
        throw err;
    Collection = db.collection('messages');
    console.log("connected to DB");
});

app.get("/*", function(request, response) {
    var screen = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    check = String(screen).split("=");
    check2 = String(screen).split("/");
    if (check[0] != "/screen" && check2[1] != "html") {
        response.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
    } else {
        if (check[1]>0 && check[1]<4) {
            saveScreen = check[1];
            response.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/oldIndex.html');
        } else if (check2[1] == "html") {
            response.sendFile(__dirname + screen);
        } else {
            response.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
        }
    }
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('sendId', function(stationId) {
        socketMap[parseInt(stationId)] = socket;
    });
    socket.on('getMessages', function(unUsed) {
        res = [];
        Collection.find({"screensId":{'$eq': parseInt(saveScreen)}}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
            docs.forEach(function(doc) {
                res.push(doc);
            });
            socket.emit('sendMessages', res);
        });
    });
    socket.on('getAllMessages',function(unUsed){
        res = [];
        Collection.find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
            docs.forEach(function(doc) {
                res.push(doc);
            });
            console.log("STAM CHECK:" + res[0].name);
            socket.emit('sendAllMessages', res);
        });
    });
});
```

main.js code (for roting,service and controllers):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',
            {
                controller: 'HomeController',
                templateUrl: 'menu.html'
            })
        .when('/stations',
            {
                controller: 'StationsController',
                templateUrl: 'messagesView.html'
            })
        .when('/',
            {
                controller: 'HomeController',
                templateUrl: 'menu.html'
            })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});
 var customersService = function ($http, $q) {
        var addsFactory = {};
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
        addsFactory.getMessages = function () {
            socket.emit('getAllMessages',null);
            socket.on('sendAllMessages',function (result) {
                return result;
            });
        };
        return addsFactory;
 };
  myApp.factory('customersService', ['$http', '$q', customersService]);


myApp.controller('StationsController',function($scope,customersService){
    $scope.messages = [];
    $scope.messages = customersService.getMessages();
});

myApp.controller('HomeController',function($scope){
    $scope.message="Loaded Menu!!";
});
```

can somone help me know what is my problem?

Comment: Nothing returned from `getMessages()`. A `return` from inner function does not return to outer function so `return result` is doing nothing

Comment: so how can i return something from anonymus function to outer function?

Comment: could replace the anonymous function with a callback passed in as argument. Will need to use `$apply` in order to tell angular to run a digest also

Comment: could you write me an example of how to do so?

Comment: Do a google search for "angular socket" will find numerous factories  and tutorials. Important to understand that changing scope outside of angular core requires using `$apply`

Answer (score -1):

You have your `addsFactory.getMessages` encapsulated in a variable `customersService`. Then in an outer function you are trying to invoke that with `customersService.getMessages();`. The way you have defined this is that customersService is itself a function and within that there is a `addsFactory` object with a function `getMessages`. Can you see how your function invocation doesn't match that? There are all sorts of ways you could remedy this. You need to define this function in an outer scope:

```
function getMessages(socket) {
    socket.emit('getAllMessages',null);
    socket.on('sendAllMessages',function (result) {
        return result;
    });
};
```

This way you expose the `getMessages` function to your controller and give it a `socket` argument. Then you could just invoke this by `getMessages(io.connect('http://localhost:8080');` and pass that returned value to whatever you want. You should read up on some angular best practices. I recommend [John Papa's style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide).

Comment: don't think you have interpreted the factory function properly

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that he actually defined `customersService` as a factory, still the reason that he's getting an undefined value is that he's not referencing the `addsFactory.getMessages` function correctly. He could keep the factory function, but then he needs to rewrite it in a manner that exposes `getMessages` to the controller. From what I can tell, putting that function within an object (`addsFactory`) serves no purpose, neither does injecting `$http` and `$q`